# Are There Simple Conditions for Determining When $F[X] = F(X)$?

Tags: galois-theory

1. Let $F$ be a field.
2. Consider $F(X)$ -- the **field** of all rational fractions of polynomials of $X$.
3. On the other hand, we have also $F[X]$ -- the **ring** of all polynomials of $X$.
4. Clearly, $F[X] \subseteq F(X)$ no matter what.
5. But are there simple (or common) conditions for determining whether $F[X] = F(X)$?

EDIT: As the comments below have demonstrated, if $X$ is an indeterminate then this question is easily answerable.  What happens if we let $X \in E$ for some extension field $E$ containing $F$?

Comment: Yes, the condition is $0=1$.

Comment: Ask yourself: Is there any way $\frac1X$ can be in $F[X]$?

Comment: Concerning your EDIT: This happens iff $X$ is algebraic. You can prove this directly, or have a look at an arbitrary introduction to field extension. It also appeared at least 10 times on math.SE.

Comment: Hint: write down an algebraic equation that $X$ satisfies, and then use it to solve for $1/X$ in terms of $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Martin and @kahen have indicated, it is never true. One way to see this is that $F(X)$ is a field, and so has no non-trivial ideals. However, $F[X]$ does, namely the ideal $(X)$.

Comment: In other words, $X$ is non-zero and not a unit.